# Mouse is freezing in Ubuntu/Xubuntu/Lubuntu

Tags: 11.10, 12.04, freeze

I'm using Ubuntu for a while now but since 11.10 I noticed some strange behavior. And even with Lubuntu, Xubuntu and Kubuntu I have the same problem.

Problem: After I logged into my account and used the system for while I am unable to use the system with my mouse. I can navigate through the open windows using the keyboard and even close them, start new, etc.

I can move the mouse over the whole desktop but cannot click on anything, even in the window which seems to be focused a click with the mouse has no effect on a button.Sometimes I able do draw some squares with the mouse on the desktop but nothing more.

The problem even occurs when I am using a live cd/usb stick. When using an installtion of -buntu in a virtual PC there are no problems. So this problem only exist when it is installed as a "real" OS.

In an older installation of Ubuntu I solved it by right-clicking on the window which seems to be focused and after that the mouse was "released" but this time this does not work.

My system:

- OS: Xubuntu 12.04
- Mouse: Trust Max Track
- CPU: AMD Athlon II X3 425
- Graphics: ATI Radeon HD 4550

Comment: So your system does not freeze, does it? The mouse is "imprisoned" in some window, but does it moves?

Comment: Well, freeze was not the rigth word I know. Imprisoned is a little bit more exact but also not really correct because I can move the mouse over the whole desktop but cannot click on anything, even in the window which seems to be focused a click with the mouse has no effect on a button.Sometimes I able do draw some squares with the mouse on the desktop but nothing more.

Comment: Seems to be a mouse problem.I suggest you update the title and the explanation to increase the chance of answers ;-)

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't sound like it's your issue, but all troubleshooting should start with the basics. I think this only applies if you're using a touchpad, but Ubuntu has a feature which is supposed to disable your mouse while you type. It caused some issues for me in the past. [Here's more information about it.](https://help.ubuntu.com/11.04/ubuntu-help/mouse-disabletouchpad.html)

For me, unchecking that box solved my issues. If this isn't the case for you, please update your question with more information about your installation, and the mouse you're using.

Comment: I don't use a touchpad but thank you for your answer :) I'll update my question